# Dissmiss the context menu of SelectableText without clicking a menu item

Tags: flutter

In case of native, if I click any empty area or press the back button, the menu disappears. In case of Flutter, clicking empty area does nothing, and pressing the back button closes the app. Is there no way to dismiss the context menu without clicking an item like "Copy"?

Also, when I ran the same project for Windows desktop, selecting the text shows no context menu. I tried right click, and long left click, but none of them made the context menu appear. How can I show the menu on Windows?

[image]

```
        SelectableText(
          "Hello world",
        ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your Scaffold with tap event (i.e GestureDetector) and use FocusScopeNode with unfocus() to dismiss the SelectableText

```
return GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
    if(!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
      currentFocus.focusedChild.unfocus();
    }
  },
  child: Scaffold(
    body: SelectableText("Hello World")
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks. It seem to be working. But if the empty area that I click to dismiss the context menu happens to be the floating button at the bottom, "Select all" still remains, for some reason.

Comment: @DamnVegetables what does your onPressed() of FloatingActionButton do? Assuming you're using this widget.

Comment: It was from the project template, so it was just increasing the click count variable.

Comment: You can also add the unfocus() code above to onPressed() of FloatingActionButton.